# Get data from ODBC in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a typical project that uses "% work complete". This value actually is entered in an ERP which could be accessed by an ODBC connection. However, I can't figure out how to open this connection. Using VBA I get a compilation error in this line

```
 Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
```

Is it even possible to gather data from an ODBC source in MS Project?

Comment: Probably you are simply missing a reference to ADODB: In VBA choose `Tools ->References` and check `Microsoft Active X DataObjects x.x Library`. I never tried but am sure it is possible to access a data source via ADO in MS Project.

Comment: That was it, stupid mistake. Thanks for the hint